Does the Overcharge perk apply to weapons and melee?
I have levelled up my Heavy now, and I have access to the Overcharge perk.

The fact the icon is the Heavy's charged melee stomp, makes me wonder if this perk applies to Plasma weapons which can also be charged.
So does it apply to both weapons and melee?
